# How to go back to the previous screen from left_action_items of MDToolbar in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivymd

I followed the steps in KivyMD documentation to create a NavigationDrawer, so, I created it and everything work correctely, but the problem is to return to the first screen. I want to go back to the first screen (the Screen with name: 'main') when I click in the arrow-left in the MDToolbar, but nothing that I did worked.

KV File:

```
<ItemDrawer>:
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    on_release: self.parent.set_color_item(self)

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: root.text_color

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: '8dp'
    spacing: '8dp'

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        size_hint_y: .3

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: 'Reminders'
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                    root.screen_manager.current = 'RemindersWindow'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: 'bookmark-outline'

            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: 'To Do'
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                    root.screen_manager.current = 'ToDoWindow'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: 'check-outline'

            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                    root.screen_manager.current = 'SettingsWindow'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: 'cog-outline'

            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: 'About'
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                    root.screen_manager.current = 'AboutWindow'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: 'information-outline'

Screen:

    MDNavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: 'main'
                MDToolbar:
                    title: 'Remindy'
                    elevation: 10
                    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('open')]]

                MainScreen:

            Screen:
                name: 'SettingsWindow'
                FloatLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Settings'
                        elevation: 10
                        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                        left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: x]]

                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Themes'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .8}
                        on_release: app.picker_theme()
                        IconLeftWidget
                            icon: 'palette-outline'
                        
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Language'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .7}
                        on_release:
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: 'earth'

            Screen:
                name: 'RemindersWindow'

                FloatLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        elevation: 10
                        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                        left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: x]]

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'My Reminders'
                    halign: 'center'

            Screen:
                name: 'AboutWindow'

                FloatLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        elevation: 10
                        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                        left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: x]]

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'About'
                    halign: 'center'

            Screen:
                name: 'ToDoWindow'

                FloatLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        elevation: 10
                        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                        left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: x]]

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'To-Do'
                    halign: 'center'

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer

<MainScreen@FloatLayout>:
    name: 'MainScreen'
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: 'pencil-plus-outline'
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y': .1/2}
            on_release: root.datacard()

<CardScreen>:

    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDCard:
            size_hint: .8, .1

            MDLabel:
                id: base_label
                text: 'New Reminder'

<CardBox>:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: .7, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .5
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Add a Reminder'
            font_style: 'H6'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            halign: 'center'
        
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'window-close'
            on_release: root.closecard()

    MDFloatLayout:

        MDTextField:
            id: title_id
            hint_text: 'Title'
            max_text_length: 15
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: 'on_error'
            helper_text: 'This Field is Required.'
            size_hint_x: .8
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .1}

    MDFloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            icon: 'clock-time-four-outline'
            text: 'Hour'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .3}
            on_release: root.picker_hora()
                
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            icon: 'calendar-outline'
            text: 'Date'
            pos_hint: {'x': .6, 'y': .3}
            on_release: root.picker_data()

    MDFloatLayout:

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Add'
            size_hint_x: .8
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .2}
```

Python File:

```
import pickle
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import StringProperty
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDThemePicker
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDTimePicker
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def datacard(self):
        self.add_widget(CardBox())

class CardBox(MDCard):
    def closecard(self):
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)

    def picker_hora(self):
        time_dialog = MDTimePicker()
        time_dialog.open()

    def picker_data(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.open()

    def new_card(self):
        # Remove and Create a New Card
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        title = self.ids.title_input.text
        self.add_widget(CardScreen())
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.base_label.text = title

class CardScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ReminderApp(MDApp):
    Window.size = (400, 600)

    def picker_theme(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

ReminderApp().run()
```

Comment: You have to assign some action(s) to the left buttons in order to make it happen.

Comment: You say in lambda x: x? If yes, I know that the x is where I put the code to change the screen, my doubt is how I do that or what code I need to put.

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Updated, all code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger some action from the button associated to `MDToolbar` to switch to another screen.

For simple usage you can use the default function `setattr` as,

```py
left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda *args : setattr(screen_manager, "current", "main")]]
```

Or for advanced usage you can refer to a function from some relevant class say, the App's subclass, as,

```py
left_action_items: [["arrow-left", app.go_home]]
```

Now in that method,

```py
    def go_home(self, *args):
        # Access the `ScreenManager` and change the screen.
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "main"
        # Some other actions.
```

Also as a side note, you should change the line `<MainScreen@FloatLayout>` in `kvlang` with just `<MainScreen>` as you already defined it in `.py`. Otherwise a warning may be raised in log.